# Listviews & Divisions

Tags: apex, list-view

When one of our users run this custom listview (that I created) he is seeing the listview getting constrained by division.

[image]

I did some searching and found from the following link where it is mentioned  “Affected by Divisions” will affect "List Views" against Divisions.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_division.htm&language=en_US

My Qs

1. Can someone tell me how to ensure my custom listview is ran against ALL records instead of constrained by divisions ?.
2. Can someone tell me where this permission is available for me to edit ?
3. I also noticed that ,while logging in as the user, during custom list view loading there appears a Divison picklist in the left side that contains "--All--" as one of the choices. But the picklist appears only for like 1 sec before it vanishes. Pasting the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: I will assume you've reviewed all the details from the success site regarding Divsions?   https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_division.htm&language=en_US

Comment: And this covers setup/configuration of divisions
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getting_started_with_divisions.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Apologies:  not trying to be difficult, the link above didn't work for my original click.  reposted that same link.

Comment: Tx for the help. A similar custom view is not causing such problems for other users except this particular user to whom it is always coming as constrained by division. Could this be related to how the user was set up or something ?

Comment: I think its the way list view has been setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was more with respect to user and his search options page.
In the search options page for division picklist he has chosen a specific division instead of "--All--".
Once this is set, he was able to view all records across all divisions.

[image]

Comment: so you had original issue on search or list views?

Comment: List views..Looks like the options mentioned above is driving the visibility at list views also

Answer (score 1):

I think the prime permission that guides the behavior of Divisions is **"Affected By Divisions"** permission on profile. 
Please note that you can set the **Division Name** when creating or editing a list view. The current user-level selectable division will not change which results are displayed in your custom list view. 
To view records across all divisions, change your user-level selectable division to **“—All—”** or when creating a custom list view, set Division Name to **“—All—”**.

**Filter by Division on List View** :
If your organization uses divisions to segment data and you have the “Affected by Divisions” permission, select the division that records in the list view must match. This option is **disabled** if you are not searching all records.
Select --Current-- to show records in your current working division.

Comment: Hi Amit I followed your suggestion but "Division Name" is not available as one of the filter columns.

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if its more clear now.